# php mysql not updating row in proper way

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column which name is possession1, in this column I concat the $month.$year, but problem is when I update only $month then $year value is laps but when I update only $year then $month do not laps but $year update the column with old value and new value like,If month is May and old year is 2013, and when I update only year with 2014 then its showing output May20132014, this is my code

```
<select id="month" name="month" >
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
</select>

<select id="year" name="year">
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>

$month=@$_POST['month'];
$year=@$_POST['year'];
$arr = array($month, $year);
$possession1 = join("", $arr);

$updateSale="update sale set possession='$possession1' where id='$update_id'";
$r=mysql_query($updateSale);
```

Comment: What is @$_POST[]?, I mean what does the '@' there?

Comment: @gbestard It's to suppress warnings in case the post value isn't set.

Comment: Using @ to suppress warning is not a good practice as I know, indeed to use to check the reason for warning and change the code according.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Use isset to check the post value,

```
if(isset($_POST['month']) && isset($_POST['year'])){
 $month = $_POST['month'];
 $year = $_POST['year'];
 $possession1 = $month. " ".$year;
 $updateSale="update sale set possession='".$possession1."' where id='$update_id'";
 $r=mysql_query($updateSale);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @KrishR but its still not working :(

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` can you post this out put?

Comment: after use var_dump($_POST); the output is 89PROPERTY42ResidentialFlat44444.00array(24) { ["month"]=> string(34) "November 2023 2013 2014 2012 2014" ["year"]=> string(0) "" "1" ["updatenow"]=> string(6) "Update" }

Comment: seems, some other conflicts in your code, for the shared code my answer does works. Posted html code is your working area code right ?

Comment: my HTML code is so long so I can not post it here so I post some html and php code where I'm stuck

Comment: because in my html code php code are also include so its length is so large and have large amount of code so when i'll put it here then it will look so Unsightly :(

Answer (score 0):

Correct your query to this--

```
$updateSale="update sale set possession='".$possession1."' where id='".$update_id."'";
```

Comment: What? In what way would that help?

Comment: This solution did not answer the OP's issue.

Comment: Both are valid in PHP. Discouraged but ok non the less

Comment: thanks for your reply @shashank but its also not working